# Contour integral $\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1-x^3)^{1/3}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to find $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1-x^3)^{1/3}}$$ using contour integral where the contour is obtained by connecting three small circles around $\zeta^0,\zeta,\zeta^2$ ($\zeta$ is the 3rd root of unity) with straight lines and oriented positively. This contour looks like a fidget spinner containing the three branch cuts that are line segments from $\zeta^i$ to $0$.

I don't know which branch I should choose to compute the contour integral. Also, the integral from $0$ to $1$ will cancel the integral from $1$ to $0$. What's the remedy for that?

Comment: Why to invoke contour integration when the Beta and Gamma functions instantly solve this? $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}}=\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{1}x^{-2/3}(1-x)^{-1/3}\,dx =\frac{1}{3}B\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right)=\frac{\pi}{3\sin\frac{\pi}{3}}=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: Because sometimes we are not inquiring about the answer to a problem per se but we are trying to learn about particular techniques and how they would apply to that problem.

Comment: The integral from 0 to 1 should not cancel the integral from 1 to 0. AS you go around the point $(1,0)$, the argument of the factor $(1-z)$ in the denominator should change by $2\pi$.